# AspectJ annotation on field that triggers @Before advice

Tags: java, annotations, field, aspectj

I have already written AspectJ aspects that perform @Around advice triggered by method annotations. Now I want to do the same, but where fields are annotated instead of methods. So with each method invocation of the class below, it must set the accountSummary field to the correct implementation.  Is there a way to accomplish this? I presume using @Before advice would be the best way of going about it. Using CDI is not an option - the solution must use AspectJ.

```
public class PoolableBusinessLogic {
   @InjectServiceClientAdapter(legacy=LegacyAccountSummary.class,new=NewAccountSummary.class)
   private AccountSummary accountSummary;

   public void foo() {
      // use correct accountSummary impl, decided in @Before code
   }

   public void bar() {
      // use correct accountSummary impl, decided in @Before code
   }
}
```

Comment: I've solved this by creating two annotations, a type annotation (ServiceClientAdapterConsumer) and a field annotation (InjectServiceClientAdapter) with the following pointcut: @Pointcut("within(@ServiceClientAdapterConsumer *) && execution(public * *(..))"). Then in the @Before advice, I iterate through the fields of the annotated class and inject the correct implementation for any field annotated with InjectServiceClientAdapter. Is there a way of accomplishing this without the class annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve, so I am presenting two alternative solutions.

First, let us create some **application classes** in order to have a fully compileable sample:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public interface AccountSummary {
    void doSomething();
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class LegacyAccountSummary implements AccountSummary {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I am " + this);
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class NewAccountSummary implements AccountSummary {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I am " + this);
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InjectServiceClientAdapter {
    Class<?> legacyImpl();
    Class<?> newImpl();
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class PoolableBusinessLogic {
    @InjectServiceClientAdapter(legacyImpl = LegacyAccountSummary.class, newImpl = NewAccountSummary.class)
    private AccountSummary accountSummary;

    public void foo() {
        accountSummary.doSomething();
    }

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("Account summary is " + accountSummary);
    }
}
```

Now we need an **entry point**:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            PoolableBusinessLogic businessLogic = new PoolableBusinessLogic();
            businessLogic.foo();
            businessLogic.bar();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously this yields an error because the member `accountSummary` has not been initialised:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.scrum_master.app.PoolableBusinessLogic.foo(PoolableBusinessLogic.java:8)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:7)
```

Now we have two options, depending on what you want to achieve:

**Option A: dynamic injection**

Scenario: For each field access (even in the same `PoolableBusinessLogic` instance) decide dynamically what type of object instance to return. Here in this example I will just be randomising in order to simulate another if-else criterion.

BTW, I hope it is okay that I use the more expressive native AspectJ syntax. You can easily convert the aspect to annotation style.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.util.Random;
import org.aspectj.lang.SoftException;
import de.scrum_master.app.InjectServiceClientAdapter;

public aspect DynamicInjectionAspect {
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    Object around(InjectServiceClientAdapter adapterAnn) :
        get(* *) && @annotation(adapterAnn)
    {
        try {
            Class<?> implClass = RANDOM.nextBoolean() ? adapterAnn.legacyImpl() : adapterAnn.newImpl();
            return implClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SoftException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This yields the following output:

```
I am de.scrum_master.app.LegacyAccountSummary@4d9cfefb
Account summary is de.scrum_master.app.NewAccountSummary@7e28388b

I am de.scrum_master.app.NewAccountSummary@2986e62
Account summary is de.scrum_master.app.LegacyAccountSummary@6576e542

I am de.scrum_master.app.NewAccountSummary@60c58418
Account summary is de.scrum_master.app.LegacyAccountSummary@4763754a

I am de.scrum_master.app.NewAccountSummary@52a971e3
Account summary is de.scrum_master.app.NewAccountSummary@7274187a

I am de.scrum_master.app.LegacyAccountSummary@23f32c4a
Account summary is de.scrum_master.app.LegacyAccountSummary@31e0c0b6
```

As you can see, within each of the five output groups (i.e. for each `PoolableBusinessLogic` instance) there are different account summary object IDs and sometimes (not always) even different class names.

**Option B: static injection**

Scenario: Per `PoolableBusinessLogic` instance decide dynamically what type of object instance to statically assign to the annotated member if its value is `null`. After that, do not overwrite the member anymore but return the previously initialised value. Again I will just be randomising in order to simulate another if-else criterion.

Attention: Do not forget to deactivate the first aspect, e.g. by prepending `if(false) &&` to its pointcut. Otherwise the two aspects will be conflicting with each other.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Random;
import org.aspectj.lang.SoftException;
import de.scrum_master.app.InjectServiceClientAdapter;

public aspect StaticInjectionAspect {
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    before(InjectServiceClientAdapter adapterAnn, Object targetObj) :
        get(* *) && @annotation(adapterAnn) && target(targetObj)
    {
        try {
            Field field = targetObj.getClass().getDeclaredField(thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.get(targetObj) != null)
                return;
            Class<?> implClass = RANDOM.nextBoolean() ? adapterAnn.legacyImpl() : adapterAnn.newImpl();
            field.set(targetObj,implClass.newInstance());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SoftException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a bit uglier because it involves using reflection for finding the member field. Because it might be (and in our example really is) private we need to make it accessible before doing anything with it.

This yields the following output:

```
I am de.scrum_master.app.NewAccountSummary@20d1fa4
Account summary is de.scrum_master.app.NewAccountSummary@20d1fa4

I am de.scrum_master.app.NewAccountSummary@2b984909
Account summary is de.scrum_master.app.NewAccountSummary@2b984909

I am de.scrum_master.app.LegacyAccountSummary@1ae3043b
Account summary is de.scrum_master.app.LegacyAccountSummary@1ae3043b

I am de.scrum_master.app.LegacyAccountSummary@2e2acb47
Account summary is de.scrum_master.app.LegacyAccountSummary@2e2acb47

I am de.scrum_master.app.LegacyAccountSummary@7b87b9fe
Account summary is de.scrum_master.app.LegacyAccountSummary@7b87b9fe
```

Now the output looks different: Within each of the five output groups (i.e. for each `PoolableBusinessLogic` instance) both output lines show exactly the same object ID.

Comment: Wow! This is by far the best answer to any of my questions anywhere on any forum. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For **Option A: dynamic injection** in kriegaex's answer, the annotation-style aspect will look like this:

```
@Aspect
public class InjectServiceClientAdapterAspect {
    @Pointcut("get(* *) && @annotation(injectAnnotation)")
    public void getServiceClientAdapter(InjectServiceClientAdapter injectAnnotation) {
    }

    @Around("getServiceClientAdapter(injectAnnotation)")
    public Object injectServiceClientAdapter(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, final InjectServiceClientAdapter injectAnnotation) {      
       // injection code goes here                                          
}
```